# use hub, the github-gem or just stick to git when working with github repo's?

Tags: git, github

What are the pro/con's of using:
- hub
- github-gem
- or just git
when working with github?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

- **[hub](http://github.com/defunkt/hub)**:
  pros: good integration with git, mask all github specifics
  cons: needs ruby
- **[github-gem](http://gems.github.com/list.html)**
  pros: see hub, it can be considered as one of the gems
  cons: needs ruby, [gem startup time](http://gist.github.com/284823)
- **git**
  pros: doesn't obfuscate anything (especially in case or error message)
  cons: a lot more commands to type ;)